# What are Builder, Combiner, and Splitter in scala?

Tags: scala, collections, parallel-processing

In the parallel programming course from EPFL, four abstractions for data parallelism are mentioned: `Iterator`, `Builder`, `Combiner`, and `Splitter`.

I am familiar with `Iterator`, but have never used the other three. I have seen other traits `Builder`, `Combiner`, and `Splitter` under `scala.collection` package. However, I have idea how to use them in real-world development, particularly how to use them in collaboration with other collections like `List`, `Array`, `ParArray`, etc. Could anyone please give me some guidance and examples?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think they see much use in the real world. The parallel collection library is at a quite awkward position: For truly large data sets, you'd use distributed processing framework such as Spark to process them across multiple machines. For single machine you will need a large enough data set to overcome the overhead of synchronizing across different threads/cores (see [this article](https://www.jayway.com/2011/10/02/experimenting-with-scala-parallel-collections/)). And for those special cases, using a streaming approach would be much better in terms of memory usage.

Comment: Not every component in any library is supposed to be used or is supposed to have a practical use. Some (actually most) components are supposed to be never interacted with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two traits `Iterator` and `Builder` are not specific to parallelism, however, they provide the basis for `Combiner` and `Splitter`.

- You already know that an `Iterator` can help you with iterating over sequential collections by providing the methods `hasNext` and `next`. A `Splitter` is a special case of an `Iterator` and helps to partition a collection into multiple *disjoint* subsets. The idea is that after the splitting, these subsets can be processed in parallel. You can obtain a `Splitter` from a parallel collection by invoking `.splitter` on it. The two important methods of the `Splitter` trait are as follows:

  - `remaining: Int`: returns the number of elements of the current collection, or at least an approximation of that number. This information is important, since it is used to decide whether or not it's worth it to split the collection. If your collection contains only a small amount of elements, then you want to process these elements sequentially instead of splitting the collection into even smaller subsets.
  - `split: Seq[Splitter[A]]`: the method that actually splits the current collection. It returns the disjoint subsets (represented as `Splitter`s), which recursively can be splitted again if it's worth it. If the subsets are small enough, they finally can be processed (e.g. filtered or mapped).
- `Builder`s are used internally to create new (sequential) collections. A `Combiner` is a special case of a `Builder` and at the same time represents the counterpart to `Splitter`. While a `Splitter` splits your collection before it is processed in parallel, a `Combiner` puts together the results afterwards. You can obtain a `Combiner` from a parallel collection (subset) by invoking `.newCombiner` on it. This is done via the following method:

  - `combine(that: Combiner[A, B]): Combiner[A, B]`: combines your current collection with another collection by "merging" both `Combiner`s. The result is a new `Combiner`, which either represents the final result, or gets combined again with another subset (by the way: the type parameters `A` and `B` represent the element type and the type or the resulting collection).

*The thing is that you don't need to implement or even use these methods directly if you don't define a new parallel collection*. The idea is that people implementing new parallel collections only need to define splitters and combiners and get a whole bunch of other operations for free, because those operations are already implemented and make use of splitters and combiners.

Of course this is only a superficial description of how those things work. For further reading, I recommend reading [Architecture of the Parallel Collections Library](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/architecture.html) as well as [Creating Custom Parallel Collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/custom-parallel-collections.html).